# How multi currency wallet gets connected to different blockchains?

Tags: wallets, multisignature

How multi currency wallet is getting connected to different blockchains and how public and private key is managed in it?

If I want to develop multi currency wallet then how can I connect to different blockchains using different clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wallets do not get connected to different blockchains.
- Instead, wallets manage the private keys of accounts/addresses (or public keys) which might be from different blockchains.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I want to know which client they are using while transferring currency, is there any need of multiple client, if there is need then how it is managed?